# How to change angle_min- angle_max and time_increment on laserscan message

Tags: ros, 2dlaserscan, sensor-msgs, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I use urg-04lx ug01 hokuyo lidar and its range 240 degree. but in LaserScan.msg shows like below:
angle_min: -2.35619449615
angle_max:2.09234976768
angle_increement: 0.00613592332229
time_increement: 9.76562732831e-05
is these parameters are normal?  -2.35619449615 radyan is  about -135 degree
2.09234976768 radyan  is about 120 degree     is there no mistake??
And how do I change these values? For example ı want to angle_min =0 angle_max=240

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284690/how-to-change-angle_min--angle_max-and-time_increment-on-laserscan-message/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have some [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials) available to dynamically reconfigure the parameters.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-03-07**:
thank you very much:)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

you can change angel min and angel max in your launch file in this [link](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/blob/indigo-devel/launch/urg_lidar.launch)  an example launch file just edit angel min and angel max

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2018-03-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-03-07**:
thank you Mr. @hamid